# Example of how to convert postgres text time with am/pm to a timestamp

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timestamp

I have a date time field in postgres like 06/29/2022 1:24 pm and I'd like to cast it to 2022-06-29 13:32:00

I know it's something close to this

select to_timestamp(created, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS p')

but I cannot find an example for the am/pm part.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like this:

```
select to_timestamp('06/29/2022 1:24 pm', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh12:mi am,pm');
```

Comment: You just need to use one of either `AM` or `PM` it will do the right thing in either case.

Comment: Thank you for this, I had the formatting in my head wrong.